# text align or margin 0 auto both not working to center div

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #circles {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .circle {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: blue;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="circles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried using `margin: 0 auto` and `text-align: center`, but none of these methods seem to work to center the inner divs. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Set a width for the circles and then use `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`.

```css
#circles {
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="circles">
  <div class="circle"></div><!--
  --><div class="circle"></div><!--
  --><div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're opening a comment after the last circle ;)

Comment: @chrona that's for white space fix, he also closes them before he starts another element

Comment: For removing the space which is occurred by `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Does he need to use the comment after the last element? Chrona was pointing at that, I guess he already knows the trick about inline-block elements space removal.

Comment: @chrona [This](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) can help you

Comment: @ManojKumar I always add. It is safe.

Comment: @ManojKumar nope, he doesn't have to use that last comment, infact its invalid

Comment: Yeah I'm aware how it works, I wanted to say you were commenting out the `</div>` from `id="circles"`. (all good now)

Comment: @ManojKumar I don't have any comment after the last child

Comment: @ManojKumar Oh I got ii

Answer (score 0):

You have got `float:left` in `.circle` delete it and add `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

That because you are using div which property display is block. Then you you try to center it using text-align: center but you are also left aligning it. Set display to inline-block and remove float property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#circles
{
  display: inline-block;
}
.circle
{
    width:30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
   <div id = "circles">
     <div class = "circle"></div>
     <div class = "circle"></div>
     <div class = "circle"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rrzu3a1w/

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your div a width before setting `margin` to auto

```
#your_div {
  width: 700px ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a float:left in your class .circle so the .circle divs are not listening to the text align center of their parent. Remove the float left and use a display inline-block instead.